# Debug a Sql Server stored procedure using output files

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, debugging, sql-server-2005

I have to debug a large stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 (also in 2005).

because I can't go in that procedure StepByStep, I need to debug it using some output files.

actually i use something like

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @SQL = 'BCP "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE" QUERYOUT "D:\TDB\test.txt" -C -T -w' 
EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @SQL
```

but this approach has multiple limitations like impossibility to use # tables, and a complex way to use filters (where X='+cast(@MYLocalVar as varchar)+')...

Is there a other way to output a *select* to a file, like *MySql* does

```
SELECT * into outfile '../../htdocs/VIP/Temp/temp.txt' from tmp_Menu2;
```

Comment: Why not just output the results into a table, perhaps in another database, and investigate that?

Comment: but I need to create a table, each time columns should correspond to the concrete situation, by ex joins or selective selects...is a little embarrassing, and if I use other database I need to build that tables in an other database...

Answer (score 0):

You can put the data into a table quite readily:

```
SELECT *
into      anotherdatabase..outtable
from . . .
```

This creates a new table with whatever columns you want.

To output something into a file requires an extra step, using `bulk export`.

Comment: First of all, I need to create manually a table for each of my select.
Second I need to create delimited multiple outputs for each of the cycle (in a while, by ex). I can do it my outputing the result to different output files "myFile"+@currrentId+".txt"

Comment: the bulk export is not in the same session, so I cant use the #tables to touput.

Comment: To use a temporary table, you would want to use a global temporary . . . ##tables.  You could also combine the results using xml, but that would require more changes to the queries than just adding an `into` clause.

Comment: my current stored procedures uses the # tables, not the ## tables... So I just want to debug it, I don't need or want to modify the procedures, but adding some "select * into output@myid.txt from #mytable"